# Opposite of Quarantine

Tags: antonyms

As I understand it, quarantine is used to describe the isolation of the infected to prevent spread of infection. However, I'm looking for a word for the isolation of the healthy to avoid infection.

Comment: The question is based on a misunderstanding (a common misconception) of the term. *The term is often erroneously used to mean medical isolation, which is "to separate ill persons who have a communicable disease from those who are healthy."* (WP, see below). So it works both ways.

Comment: Look here: Wikipedia, *Quarantine**: "A quarantine is used to separate and restrict the movement of persons; it is a 'state of enforced isolation'.[1] This is often used in connection to disease and illness, such as those who may possibly have been exposed to a communicable disease.[2] ... The word comes from the Italian (seventeenth-century Venetian) quaranta, meaning forty, which is the number of days ships were required to be isolated before passengers and crew could go ashore during the Black Death plague epidemic.[4] "  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quarantine

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's no single directly fitting antonym, however, there are a few options to convey your meaning:

- *Reverse quarantine* - this uses negation to create the meaning
- *Isolation* - this conveys the general meaning, and can be used in a medical context
- *Protective sequestration* - this fits best with your intended meaning, "isolating a still-healthy population to prevent diesease from spreading to it"

Sources:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protective_sequestration

Comment: Protective sequestration seems to be a very good fit for what I'm looking for, many thanks :)

Comment: *Isolation* and *sequestration* are synonyms for *quarantine* itself.

Comment: That term was invented to distinguish from a specific use of *quarantine* -- *The term “protective sequestration” avoids the use of the word quarantine, which, in public health, refers to the voluntary or enforced detention of a person who, because of actual or possible contact with a person carrying an infectious agent, may have acquired that agent and be capable of passing it along to others.* (ibid.)

Comment: Also @NVZ According to dictionaries, *protective sequestration* is a type of *quarantine*.  It's a hyponym, definitely not an opposite term.

Answer (score 0):

When the **infected** are **quarantined**, the **healthy** are **insulated**.